# General solution for a linear differential equation of second order (Weber differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$R''(z)+\lambda^2*(\frac{-z^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2})*R(z)=0$$

The differential equation is only one part of the bigger differential equation. I have solved the other part which was only an ODE of 2 order. Is there a way to solve this?

lambda here is just a constant!
Also, according to Wolfram Alpha this is a Weber differential equation.

Comment: Please note that it is a LINEAR ODE only.

Answer (score 1):

When $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$, you may check that $R(z)=e^{-z^2/2}$ is one solution. Otherwise this equation is parabolic Cylinder ODE whose solution is discussed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function

Comment: You mean now $\lambda$ constant or the eigenvalues?

Comment: ok i think you mean the eigenvalue there.

Answer (score 1):

$$R''(z)+\lambda^2(\frac{-z^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2})R(z)=0$$
$$\dfrac {R''(z)}{R(z)}=-\lambda^2(\frac{-z^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2})$$
Back to the Riccati's equation we have:
$$\left(\dfrac {R'}{R}\right)'+\left(\dfrac {R'}{R}\right)^2=K^2(z^2-1)$$
Where $ 2K^2= \lambda^2$. You can only solve this DE for some particular values of $K$.  For $K=1 \implies \lambda = \sqrt 2$ It's easy to solve. Then it's like Z Ahmed's answer.
$$\dfrac {R'}{R}=-z$$
$$R'+zR=0$$
$$(Re^{z^2/2})'=0$$
$$R(z)=Ce^{-z^2/2}$$

Comment: like is it done? is that the answer? Sorry I'm a little confused here as lot of new terms in the solutions.

Comment: I added some lines for clarity @SherlockHomies

Comment: so what is the general solution? The $\lambda$ is eigenvalue right? and not the constant $\lambda$ from the question?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only solve it for some particular values of $\lambda$ @SherlockHomies

Comment: hm ok but i need to find the general solution for that. I have another equation from the boundary conditions: $R(z)=const*R'(z)$. And this looks like the same solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution to this DE you posted with elementary functions @SherlockHomies

Comment: Riccati's equation is not that easy to solve unfortunately. @SherlockHomies